# How obscure is "yet" in place of "but"?

Tags: conjunctions, archaic-language

I've seen "yet" used in place of "but" like:

> He was bulky, yet devilishly quick.
>
> You buy yourself golden earrings, yet you cannot afford medicine for your mother!

I'm fairly sure this usage is somewhat archaic, but I never got any hunch just *how* archaic it is. Would you find it in modern formal speech? Would it sound awkward in common conversation? Does it bear any special connotations different than "but"?

Comment: Not archaic and not obscure. Very common and idiomatic English.

Comment: Not exactly "obscure", but definitely far less common than "but" with that sense in speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is to be hoped that some, at least, of our visitors intend to read as well as speak.

Comment: @StoneyB: Absolutely. I just wanted to make the point that SF's perception isn't *entirely* without foundation, even if he's massively overstated the position. Taking ["I'm tired but happy"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I'm+tired+but+happy%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, (which would almost always be words actually spoken), there are apparently 145 instances in Google Books. But not a single one for the same statement using "yet" instead of "but".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the sentence you used as an example, *yet* means "but at the same time" or "nevertheless."
Using *yet* as conjunction is not archaic; it is still used nowadays.

> The path was dark, yet I slowly found my way.

Answer (score 1):

As a native US English speaker, I think "yet" sounds a little more literary or poetic or dramatic. Most people in casual conversation will probably say "but", but "yet" is certainly understandable and not archaic.